# React Fontawesome doesn't have free-brands-svg-icons, so cant show the social media icons

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome

Is there anyway i can use social media icons on my React Webpage?

`import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { fas, faHome, faMapMarker } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';`

tried to import

`import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';`

`library.add( fab, fas, faHome, faMapMarker)`

Tried to use it as both examples

`<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fab facebook-f" />`/`<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab','facebook-f']} />`

says fab cant be found on the fortawesome folder and throws an error

"Module not found: Can't resolve '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons' in 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\tourism\src'"

Comment: ``npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons``

Comment: That was fast. Thanks alot. Any idea why it doesnt gets installed with fontawesome?

Comment: not everyone depends on them, so its nice idea to split packages like that

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As @fard said:
`npm i --save @fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons`

Comment: Hey @Dav, 
Installing above commands does not work for me. Still I am facing issue of Cannot find module '@fortawesome/'.ts

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome"
import { faFacebook } from "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons"

then past the following line 
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faFacebookF} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey @Bharat looks like you're using typescript. What errors are you seeing? if it is typescript related, try adding types for related dependencies (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-fontawesome). e.g: `yarn add @types/react-fontawesome`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30114445)